# Регулярные выражения: как извлечь подстроку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть текст вида:

```
id: 12346,
title: 'Ivanov',
description: 'Смешанное содержимое',
size: 666,
```

Как извлечь отсюда значения, то есть, чтобы получилось:

```
12346
Ivanov
Смешанное содержимое
666
```

Лучше отдельно для каждой строки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю будет более универсально:

```
(?<=\w+: ).+(?=,)
```

Немного поясню.
Выражение в скобках означает положительный просмотр вперед. Это задается последовательностью символов (?<=). То есть, мы проверяем, чтоб перед искомым выражением была некоторая последовательность букв(одна или более) \w+ и двоеточие с пробелом ": "
Далее идет само выражение ".+"это любое количество символов кроме \n.
Ограничением является запятая (?=,). Аналогично положительному поиску назад - положительный поиск вперед.

Answer (score 3):

как-то так наверное

```
(\bid:\ )(\d+)
(\btitle:\ ')(\S+)',
(\bdescription:\ ')(.+)',
(\bsize:\ )(\d+)
```

[пример](http://regex101.com/r/oA4dZ9)